# Test on Room Database, iterable containing "Item" but !item 0 was "Item"

Tags: android, testing

Goog afternoon,

I search on by database to test on a specific class Test, when I put a new item, if the list contains the item.

```
@Test
public void insertAndDeleteTask() throws InterruptedException {


        Project projectTartampion = new Project(1L, "Projet Tartampion", 0xFFEADAD1);
        long projectID1L = projectDao.inserProject(projectTartampion);
        Task task1L = new Task(1,projectID1L,"Test",3);
        taskDao.insertTask(task1L);


    List<Project> allProjects = LiveDataTestUtil.getValue(projectDao.getAllProjects());
    assertNotNull(allProjects);
    assertFalse(allProjects.isEmpty());

    List<Task> allTasks = LiveDataTestUtil.getValue(taskDao.getAllTasks());
    assertNotNull(allTasks);
    assertFalse(allTasks.isEmpty());

    Log.i("TAG","***********************************"+LiveDataTestUtil.getValue(taskDao.getAllTasks()));

    assertThat(allTasks, contains(task1L));//HERE TO TEST IF allTasks contains task1L/////
```

Error result on log Test :

```
iterable containing info Task{id=1, projectId=1, name='Test', creationTimestamp=3}
         but: item 0: was Task{id=1, projectId=1, name='Test', creationTimestamp=3}
```

But I don't exactly understand what's happening, because when I use the Log.i to see if my item is in the list, it is on.

Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 0):

Exactly the error message is :

```
Expected: iterable containing [<Task{id=1, projectId=1, name='Test', creationTimestamp=3}>]
     but: item 0: was <Task{id=1, projectId=1, name='Test', creationTimestamp=3}>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I find my problem, I lost to create and transfert to a new MutableLiveData as below,

```
    MutableLiveData<List<Task>> listLiveData = new MutableLiveData<>();

    listLiveData.setValue(allTasks);
    assertEquals(listLiveData.getValue().get(0).getName(), task2L.getName());
    assertEquals(listLiveData.getValue().get(1).getName(), task1L.getName());
```

Now it is ok for the test.